# Is .NET VM a compiler or an interpreter?

Tags: .net, clr, cil, vm-implementation

Does the .NET's Virtual Machine compiles the CIL bytecode (and then execute the code at the lowest level - CPU assembler), or it is an interpreter (that reads the following instructions and execute them) ?

Comment: I ask a similar question about Java Virtual Machine. Seems that can be one or another, or even both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does the .NET's Virtual Machine
>   compiles the CIL bytecode (and then
>   execute the code at the lowest level -
>   CPU assembler)

Yes, it's a component of the CLR called [JIT](http://www.dotnet-guide.com/jit.html) (Just-In-Time compilation) that converts the Intermediary Language code (emitted by the compiler of the programming language) into a machine code.

There's no interpreter as there is in the dynamic languages such as Ruby, PHP, Python.

---

UPDATE:

As pointed out in the comments by @Nick Craver since the addition of the [DLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Language_Runtime) in .Net 4 brings the possibility of using dynamic language concepts in the CLR.

Comment: I'm not sure about the 2nd part of the answer, since the addition of the DLR in .Net 4, I could be wrong...but I think that statement needs a few caveats around it.

Comment: Both .NET framework and .NET Compact framework do JIT compilation. .NET Micro framework however uses an interpret (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework).