# How different is C# VM different from JVM?

Tags: c#, java

I am a Java developer and more recently have started working on C# and .Net

How different is C# VM different from JVM. How is it better or worse in different departments

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275360/is-net-vm-a-compiler-or-an-interpreter

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Java

Comment: Too vague and probably not constructive either.

Comment: Its better in every way, discuss! but seriously, I think it will be hard to get one objective answer here, or indeed one that serves any useful purpose.

Comment: They are not interchangeable so you there is little value in comparing them.  Depending on the language you use, you have to use one or the other.  Conversely, you wouldn't chose the language for your project on the basis of the VM.

Comment: The important point is, they both work, although there are Java VMs for a broader range of OSes.

Comment: .NET runs on Windows XP, Windows 2003, Windows Vista, Windows 7 and 8. What else could anyone want. ;)

Answer (score 1):

One runs CIL for C#, the other runs CIL for Java. That is the difference that really matters.